# Rails outputting list version of Flickr API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, flickr

I have pulled from Flickr my photo hierarchy and have the following two helpers my my Gallery helper:

```
module GalleryHelper

  def gallery_comparison(hierarchy)

    output = '<ul>'

    for collection in hierarchy["collections"]["collection"]
      output << traverse_collection(collection, 0)
    end

    output << '</ul>'
    output.html_safe
  end



  def traverse_collection(collection, parent)
    parent = parent == 0 ? 0 : parent["id"]
    o ||= ''
    o << '<li>COLLECTION: ' + collection['title'] + '</li>'

    if collection["set"]
      for set in collection["set"]

        o << '<li>ALBUM: ' + set["title"] + '</li>'

        # photos =  Flickr.photos_in_set(set["id"])
        # for photo in photos['photoset']['photo']
        #   o << '<li>' + 'a photo here' + '</li>'
        # end

      end
    end

    if collection["collection"]
      for child in collection["collection"]
        ((1))traverse_collection(child, collection)
        ((2))o << '<li>COLLECTION: ' + child["title"] + '</li>'
      end
    end

    o << 'End of traversal'
    o
  end

end
```

It basically takes the Flickr hierarchy, iterates over it and outputs an html list to my page.

My problem is that at point `**1**`, this `traverse_collection` line should call itself and it is not doing so.

If I comment out point `((1))` and use point `((2))`, I get the `child["title"]` outputted perfectly.

How can I get the `traverse_collection` to run so it calls itself?

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this simply by calling traverse_collection and sending the output to `o`

```
o << traverse_collection
```